# SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

Estoy empezando a aprender un par de cosas para diseño web, y hay algo que no funciona. Programo en Windows y cuando quiero iniciar el comando `rails s` me tira esto:

```
**PS C:\Users\Asus\hello_WWW> rails s
=> Booting Puma

=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!

*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!

*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!

Puma starting in single mode...

* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop**
```

Leyendo varios artículos, he visto que hay una especie de bug en Windows con lo que es Puma. ¿alguien me podría dar una mano? 
Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Estos nos son errores sino más bien advertencias debido a las limitantes [de Puma en Windows](https://github.com/puma/puma#platform-constraints).

En sistemas basados en Unix existen [las señales POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) que puedes [enviar a un proceso en ejecución](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html), y a su vez pueden ser manipuladas en tu proceso ruby con [`Signal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Signal.html).
Puma particularmente implementa [una serie de capturas de este tipo de señales](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/0f6ab1272a6bff0987b848a4bf59de5d7298229b/lib/puma/launcher.rb#L416-L479), las cuales claramente no son posibles de realizar en Windows.
Otras de las limitantes en Windows es la falta de forking, es por eso que recibes el mensaje `Puma starting in single mode...`, que en el fondo es iniciar Puma en un único worker, algo que en un sistema Unix-based lo lograrías cambiando tu archivo `config/puma.rb` la línea:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
```

y cambiar el `2` por `0`, o simplemente comentar la línea.
Aunque otra recomendación mejor aún es que pruebes a programar en linux u osx, ya que con rails para Windows te espera un mundo de incompatibilidades y esto puede que sea tan solo el inicio.